# Rescue.enqueue on after_commit callback returns uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm working on configuring Resque and I want to enqueue a job in an after_commit callback on my `SocialMediaPost` model. When I try to save an instance of my model, I get an `uninitialized constant SocialMediaPost::Postman` error. This is my first time working with background jobs so I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've been following the [RailsCast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrE47tCrZXc) on this as well as the readme on the Resque repo.

Here is my model `SocialMediaPost`:

```
class SocialMediaPost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :employer
    validates :post, length: {in: 0..140}, if: Proc.new { |t| t.twitter }
    validates :post, length: {in: 0..256}, if: Proc.new { |t| t.linkedin }
    after_commit :enqueue

    private

    def enqueue
        if self.scheduled_time
            options = {
                id: self.id,
                services: JSON.parse(self.services),
                posts: JSON.parse(self.posts),
                attachment_url: self.attachment_url,
                media_url: self.media_url,
                time: self.scheduled_time
            }
            Resque.enqueu(Postman, options)
        else
            post_tweet if self.twitter && self.attachment_url.blank?
            post_tweet_with_media if self.twitter && self.attachment_url.present?
            post_linkedin_status if self.linkedin
        end
    end
end
```

Here is my worker `Postman` (app/workers/postman.rb):

```
class Postman
    @queue = :social_media_posts

    def self.perform(options)
        post = SocialMediaPost.find(options.id)
        post.post_tweet if options[:services][:twitter] && options[:attachment_url].blank?
        post.post_tweet_with_media if options[:services][:twitter] && options[:attachment_url].present?
        post.post_linkedin_status if options[:services][:linkedin]
    end
end
```

Here is my `resque.rake` file:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

namespace :resque do
    puts "Loading Rails environment for Resque"
    task :setup => :environment do
        ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each { |klass|  klass.columns }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need

```
require 'postman'
```

at the top of your SocialMediaPost file.